# How to split image in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I have recently bought a UV digital printer. I'm looking to print a wall design on glass to stick onto the wall, however the bed size is 1300 x 2500 and the wall is 3000 x 2050mm, so the image will need splitting in 3 to fit on the bed.

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to import a image into Illustrator... make it 3000mm x 2050mm then split the images into 3 to import it back into the machine. They will all need to match up for the pattern too if that makes sense?

You guys will be a life saver if you can help me out here!

Comment: Clippimg mask, but actually you dont have to do anything the printer will just discard stuff outside the printable area.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the artboard tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) to create 3 different artboards of the sizes you need, and that together makes 3000x2050. Put them side by side and lay the image on it. Export as PDF using artboards, and you should have the 3 documents you need with the image split across them.